# Plotting Kaplan-Meier survival curve with only one stratum having confidence interval

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I'm plotting a few Kaplan-Meier plots using R with two strata each for my analysis, and my PI would like the plots to have only one of the strata to have confidence intervals plotted. I've looked at various Kaplan-Meier survival curve plotting functions, but there don't seem to be any functions that allow only a subset of confidence intervals to be displayed.

Are there any R packages with plotting functions that allow me to do this?

Comment: have you looked through 'survminer' or 'survival'?

Comment: I suspect you can delete the stratum-specific confidence interval data from the the data after you run the `survfit` function in `survminer`. Then you can make the KM plot with ggsurvplot. [Untested]

Comment: Ah yes, I think that'll work, thank you TJ87!